# Nested Azure Active Directory(AAD) Groups in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

Is nested AAD groups works in VSTS access?

I've nested AAD groups but the access for the nested group doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nested groups can not connect with VSTS access for now.

And ADD is not support for nested groups recently. You can refer the user voice [Add support for nested groups in Azure AD (app access and provisioning, group-based licensing](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15718164-add-support-for-nested-groups-in-azure-ad-app-acc)) for details.

Comment: Thank you Marina!!